# value returned by cv.keywait() is not the character code

Tags: opencv

i am using opencv with python binding

want to get the value of the key pressed with the following code

```
    cv.waitkey(10)
```

it gives -1 when no key is hit and this value if any of the key is hit.

```
   -1
   -1
   -1
   536870939
   -1 
   -1
```

Could anyone  help me in this please.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe it is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172170/python-opencv-cv-waitkey-spits-back-weird-output-on-ubuntu-modulo-256-maps-corre) question?

Comment: Would like to see a minimal application that reproduces the problem.

Comment: please show your code, and how you are using it.

Comment: chr(536870939 % 255) ... in your example did you press ';' by any chance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# While this bug remains unresolved:
if key != -1:
    reactTo( key % 256 ) # Note: NOT 255
```

Comment: Is the same thing applicable to C++? I'm trying to catch `CTRL` but it's not working.

Comment: Oh, it's quite different Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
>>> import cv
>>> cv.NamedWindow("keypress", 0)
>>> cv.WaitKey(10000)    #then I click on the new window and press the 'f' key
102
>>> chr(102)
'f'
```

You need to have an active window.
It seems your issue can be resolved by operating `% 255` on the return value, itsa crazy [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172170/python-opencv-cv-waitkey-spits-back-weird-output-on-ubuntu-modulo-256-maps-corre)